# Regex/Javascript to transform Degrees Decimal Minutes to Decimal Degrees

Tags: javascript, regex

I found a function in the GeoServer source that will allow me to convert Degrees Minutes Seconds to Decimal Degrees in Javascript. But i need to conver **Degrees Decimal Minutes** to Decimal Degrees.

Current function will do this:

```
   input: N 03° 01’ 37” 
   output: 30.016666666666666
```

But i need a function that will do this:

```
   input: 26° 23.90473
   output: ????
```

The best answer would be to tweak the existing RegEx but any Javascript solution that converts it will do.

Here's the current function:
***But i need it to accept Degrees Decimal Minutes instead of Degrees Minutes Seconds.***

```
dmsToDeg: function(dms) { 
        if (!dms) { 
            return Number.NaN; 
        } 
        var neg= dms.match(/(^\s?-)|(\s?[SW]\s?$)/)!=null? -1.0 : 1.0; 
        dms= dms.replace(/(^\s?-)|(\s?[NSEW]\s?)$/,''); 
        dms= dms.replace(/\s/g,''); 
        var parts=dms.match(/(\d{1,3})[.,°d]?(\d{0,2})[']?(\d{0,2})[.,]?(\d{0,})(?:["]|[']{2})?/); 
        if (parts==null) { 
            return Number.NaN; 
        } 
        // parts: 
        // 0 : degree 
        // 1 : degree 
        // 2 : minutes 
        // 3 : secondes 
        // 4 : fractions of seconde 
        var d= (parts[1]?         parts[1]  : '0.0')*1.0; 
        var m= (parts[2]?         parts[2]  : '0.0')*1.0; 
        var s= (parts[3]?         parts[3]  : '0.0')*1.0; 
        var r= (parts[4]? ('0.' + parts[4]) : '0.0')*1.0; 
        var dec= (d + (m/60.0) + (s/3600.0) + (r/3600.0))*neg; 
        return dec; 
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New function...

```
dmsToDeg: function(dms) { 
        if (!dms) { 
            return Number.NaN; 
        } 
        var neg = dms.match(/(^\s?-)|(\s?[SW]\s?$)/)!=null? -1.0 : 1.0; 
        dms = dms.replace(/(^\s?-)|(\s?[NSEW]\s?)$/,''); 
        var parts=dms.match(/(\d{1,3})[.,°d ]?\s*(\d{0,2}(?:\.\d+)?)[']?/); 
        if (parts==null) { 
            return Number.NaN; 
        } 
        // parts: 
        // 0 : degree 
        // 1 : degree 
        // 2 : minutes 


        var d= (parts[1]?         parts[1]  : '0.0')*1.0; 
        var m= (parts[2]?         parts[2]  : '0.0')*1.0; 
        var dec= (d + (m/60.0))*neg; 
        return dec; 
    }
```

I have removed the last part of the regex which captures seconds and fractions of seconds. I have added to the part which captures minutes `(?:\.\d+)?` This is a non capturing group (`?:`) - as we don't need it to be captured separate to the integer part of the minutes. It requires a decimal point (`\.`) and then one or more digits (`\d+`). The whole group is optional (`?`) - ie the input can just be integer still.

**Edit:** Based on your comments I modified it to be a little more white-space-agnostic... It now looks for an integer followed by a space or one of these chars: ".,°d" and that followed by decimal minutes. Solution also posted to your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NJDp4/6/

Comment: This is great! very close... can you make it work if the "°" is not there or there is extra spacing... see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/NJDp4/

Comment: strange how it works fine with another number though: http://jsfiddle.net/NJDp4/1/

Comment: The original wouldn't work with that input either, @capdragon.

Comment: I see, in that case, it's time for a NEW QUESTION, please try to get credit for fixing it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940743/regex-help-in-some-javascript-code

Comment: Sorry, only just back online and seen the issue. Though I see it's been fixed. I was a little concerned about the way the funtion was stripping spaces but I worked from the premise that the original function worked correctly. Glad your issue has been fixed though!

Comment: If I pass in `W125 52.4665` it generates the correct number (125.87444166666667) but shouldn't that be a negative number because it's West?